# Servlet and JSP connection in eclipse EE IDE with MYSQL database

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am new to java.I am creating dynamic web Application in eclipse EE IDE with MYSQL database. I want to connect my database to app so far I have created JSP page for view. Below is my JSP code and Servlet for connection. I am not able to connect to database with this. My JSP page work fine. But I think problem is with Servlet. And also advice to I need to made the two java file one for Servlet and other for getting data from JSP page.
Thanks in advance.

**Servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

 //Get user_name and pass_word from the JSP page


String toolfirst=request.getParameter("tname1");
String toolsecond=request.getParameter("tname2");
String toolvalue=request.getParameter("tvalue");

//Print the above got values in console

System.out.println("The username is" +toolfirst);






//Setting connection Parameters

String connectionparams=”jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tool”;

//database name

String db=”tool”;      

//Mysql user name and password   whichever  you have given during installation

String uname=”root”                   
String psword=””                 

//Declaring classes required for Database support

Connection connection=null;
ResultSet rs;
try {
// Loading the available driver for a Database communication

Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");

//Creating a connection to the required database

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tool, root, );

//Add the data into the database

String sql = "insert into usertable values (?,?)";


PreparedStatement prep =
connection.prepareStatement(sql);

//Setting the values which we got from JSP form

prep.setString(1, tname1);
prep.setString(2, tname2);
prep.executeUpdate();
prep.close();
  }catch(Exception E){

//Any Exceptions will be caught here

System.out.println(“The error is==”+E.getMessage());

}
finally{

//After the entire execution this block will execute and the connection with database gets closed

connection.close();



    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {
          $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #name').val('');
    $("#mytable tbody>tr:last").each(function() {this.reset();});
          return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="NewServlet">
<a  id="add" href="javascript:void(0)">Add another Credit card</a>
  <table id="mytable" width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
      <tr class="person">
      <td><input type="text" name="tname1" id="name" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="name" /></td>
      <td><select name="tvalue">
      <option>value1</option>
      <option>value2</option></select>
      <td><input type="text" name="tname2" id="name" /></td>
          </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
              <input type="submit" value="submit" >
  </form>
   <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know you can't connect? You are getting an error If so it would be the minimal required information to actually post the error you get. You're also throwing away a lot of valuable information, at least print exceptions using e.printStackTrace() in stead of printing only the message.

Comment: @Gimby: I am newbie in this field, hence I am just trying.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Are you getting an error or not? If so, post it.

Comment: @Gimby:I am not able to connect only I think there is error in my servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without having a detailed errormessage I would say that you have a compile error here:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tool, root, );
```

it should be at least:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tool", root, psword);
```

btw remove the `ResultSet`. You dont use it.

Comment: I have not set any password for the now.That's reason I didn't filled any thing there.

Comment: if the method expects 3 params you have to pass 3 params. what is the name of your IDE?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Comment: then you should see a red line below of the method call :-) First problem you pass no String value in the first param. Second problem: you pass 2 params where the method expects 3 params and last but not least you have placed a "," without a following param. you have three errors in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma at the end of this statement with no value after it. I think your number of arguments are incomplete. I also assume the userID and password needs to be somewhere in the argument list.

DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tool, root, );

Whoops - someone answered the question before I could post this. Guess I need to type faster.